# How can I get a.Net MVC 6 Exceptiion filter to return 401?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, exception, model-view-controller, unauthorized

I'm trying to get the following exception filter to return a 401 to the client:

```
public class UnauthenticatedFilter : IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.Exception.GetType() == typeof(NotAuthenticatedException))
            {
                    filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

It's being picked up by the following AJAX handler:

```
$(function () {    
    $(document)
        .bind('ajaxSuccess', HandleAjaxResponse)
        .bind('ajaxError', HandleAjaxResponse);
});

function HandleAjaxResponse(event, request, settings) {
    if (401 == request.status) {
        //Unauthorized, redirect to login
        window.location.replace('/Account/Login');
    }
    else if (403 == request.status) {
        //Forbidden, redirect to login
        window.location.replace('/Account/Login');
    }
}
```

How ever I can only ever get it to return either a `200 OK` or `500 InternalServerError`.  It seems to be entirely dependant on the `filterContext.ExceptionHandled` property - `true` returns `200`, false returns `500`.

How can I get this to respond with the 401 message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting `SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect`?

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
```